# Error on compile or run the application on VS2010 & SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012-express

I'm getting an error when I try to compile or run the application.

Performing a [simple tutorial](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=tutorials&id=4&section=5), I worked at first but now when I generate the project F6 or try to run it, I always get the error

> `Error 1 Unable to copy`
>   `"C:\Projects\DatabaseExampleApp\DatabaseExampleApp\App_Data\northwnd.mdf"
>   to "bin\Debug\App_Data\northwnd.mdf". The process can not access the
>   file 'bin\Debug\App_Data\northwnd.mdf' because it is being used by
>   another process. DatabaseExampleApp`

The first time when I run the app worked fine

I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- SQL Server 2012 Express 64-bits

#### EDIT:

after:

- kill the `sqlservr.exe` (is the file locker)
- delete the files myself `northwnd.* northwnd_log.*`
- generate project F6
- run the app work fine

But I have a questions:

- how kill or unload the file `northwnd.mdf` to avoid this problem?

The app compile after that but don't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing us your **connection string**, but I'm assuming you're using some kind of `AttachDbFileName=....` approach.

My recommendation for this would be: just don't do that. It's messy to fiddle around with `.mdf` files, specifying them directly by location, you're running into problems when Visual Studio wants to copy that file around - just forget about all that.

I would

- create the database on the SQL Server Express instance (`CREATE DATABASE .....` in Mgmt Studio)
- talk to the database *by its logical name* - not a physical file name

So I would put my database onto the SQL Server Express server instance, and then use a connection string something like this:

```
 Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyShinyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

No messy file names, Visual Studio won't have to copy around files at runtime or anything, your data is on the server and can be used and administered there - seems like the much cleaner and much nicer approach to me.

Comment: Indicated in the tutorial is not necessary if the MDF file is imported